# Azure ARM Template and PowerShell Module

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I have a module published on PowerShell Gallery and I want to deploy this module with Azure ARM Template. And I did not find how!

Here is my template:

```
   "resources": [
  {
     "name": "[variables('automationAccountName')]",
     "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts",
     "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
     "location": "[parameters('AutomationLocation')]",
     "tags": {
        "displayName": "Compte Automation"
     },
     "properties": {
        "sku": {
           "name": "Basic",
           "family": "B"
        }
     },
     "resources": [
        {
           "name": "[variables('powerShellGalleryModuleName')]",
           "type": "modules",
           "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
           "location": "[parameters('AutomationLocation')]",
           "properties": {
              "isGlobal": false,
              "sizeInBytes": 0,
              "contentLink": {
                    "uri": "[variables('powerShellGalleryModule')]"
              }
           }
        }
     ]
  }
]
```

What should be provided for the variable `powerShellGalleryModule`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do via the PowerShellGallery

This way :

```
            {
           "name": "[variables('powerShellGalleryModule')]",
           "type": "modules",
           "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
           "location": "[parameters('AutomationLocation')]",
           "properties": {
              "isGlobal": false,
              "sizeInBytes": 0,
              "contentLink": {
                 "uri": "[concat('https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/', variables('powerShellGalleryModule'))]"
              }
           },
           "dependsOn": [
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', variables('automationAccountName'))]"
           ]
```

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved. Please mark it as an answer so that other community members will be benefited.

Answer (score 1):

We can import these integration modules into Azure Automation using any of the following methods:

1.Using the **New-AzureRmAutomationModule** cmdlet in the AzureRm.Automation module.
2.Using the **Azure portal** and navigating to the Assets within automation account.
3.Using Azure Resource Manager (ARM) **template**

We can use ARM template to deploy our custom integration modules. Here is an example template:

```
"$schema": "http://schemas.microsoft.org/azure/deploymentTemplate?api-version=2015-01-01-preview#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0",
      "parameters": {
        "automationAccountType": {
          "type": "string",
          "allowedValues": [
            "New",
            "Existing"
          ]
        },
        "automationAccountName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "moduleName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "moduleUri":{
          "type": "string"  
        }
      },
      "variables": {
        "templatelink": "[concat('https://devopsgallerystorage.blob.core.windows.net/azureautomationpackages/templates%5Corigtemplates%5C', parameters('automationAccountType'), 'AccountTemplate.json')]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
          "name": "nestedTemplate",
          "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
          "properties": {
            "mode": "incremental",
            "templateLink": {
              "uri": "[variables('templatelink')]",
              "contentVersion": "1.0"
            },
            "parameters": {
              "accountName": {
                "value": "[parameters('automationAccountName')]"
              },
              "accountLocation": {
                "value": "[resourceGroup().Location]"
              },
              "moduleName": {
                "value": "[parameters('moduleName')]"
              },
              "moduleUri": {
                "value": "[parameters('moduleUri')]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

More information about deploy custom Azure Automation Integration module using ARM template, please refer to this [link](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2015/11/26/deploy-custom-azure-automation-integration-modules-using-arm-templates/) writed by Ravikanth.